# How to iterate through collection across two columns in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'd like to have a two-column layout to display the returned collection information. Right now I have a two-column layout like:

```
<template name="Participants">
  <div class="container">
  <h4 style="text-align: center">{{ReportsMonth}} {{ReportsCamp}} {{ReportsYear}} {{ReportsTitle}}</h4>
{{#each programReports}}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s6">
        <h5>Name: {{FullName}}</h5>
        <p>Age: {{calculateAge Bdate}}<br> Sex: {{Sex}}<br> Level: {{Level}}<br> Location: {{City}}, {{State}}</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col s6">
        <h5>Name: {{FullName}}</h5>
        <p>Age: {{calculateAge Bdate}}<br> Sex: {{Sex}}<br> Level: {{Level}}<br> Location: {{City}}, {{State}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
</template>
```

The problem of course is that when it iterates through, it repeats the document across to the next column; it only gets to the next document when it finishes row. Is there a way to have it iterate to fill each div in each row with the next document?

Example:

Current HTML Output:

```
a a
b b
```

Desired:

```
a c
b d
```

Or:

```
a b  
c d
```

Comment: Why not simply have a single `row` and let the grid system do the column flow (emit a single `col s6` each iteration)?

Comment: You are correct, sir. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way I can think of for the first example (vertical data rows, a c on same row):

1. Split your programReports into two helpers: one for the first half, one for the second half.
2. Make a row and a col s6 outside your #each loops.
3. Put your items in your each loops in a row and xs12.

I'd love it if someone had a better way to do this, as I've had to do it myself.

Horizontal data rows example (a b on same row):

1. I think for this one you simply need to get rid of the second col s6 in your each loop.  I could be misunderstanding something though.

Comment: You got it. The {{#each}} needed to be inside the div row and omit the other col s6.